# Regular Expression to find out special name pattern of folder's in PHP

Tags: php, regex

E.g: The named pattern of folder's name :

Begin with one letter and end with three or ten number.

```
F3445656
A543545
F454534535
```

And my regular expression is :

```
$path = realpath('k:\\folder\\');

$folders = new DirectoryIterator($path);
foreach($folders as $folder){
    if($folder->isDot()) continue;
    if ($folder->isDir() && preg_match('/[A-Z][0-9]{1,9}$/', $folders)){
        echo $folder;
    }
```

So, is it the right way to do?!

Thank you very much!!

Comment: I suppose you meant `[0-9]{3,10}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
preg_match('/^[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{3,9}$/i', $folders))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach was almost correct. But you forgot `^` to make it compare from the start:

```
preg_match('/^[A-Z][0-9]{1,9}$/i', $folders)
```

The `/i` is only necessary if you want to match A-Z case-insensitively. The `{1,9}` should become `{1,10}` if you want to match 1 to 10 numbers.

Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world for some nice tools that can assist in designing regular expressions.